# Need to stop my timeouts from stacking when holding keydown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm playing around with Canvas, and I'm having a problem with my 'animation' of my little dude on the canvas, when I hold down left, and he should play his little animation as he scuttles across the page, but the timeouts are stacking while holding down the button, so his animations get all screwy. How might I control the `setTimeouts` so that he does not look so damn silly, thanks!

Code relating to movement:

```
   var playerMove = function(direction) {

        if (direction === 'left') {
            updatePlayer(0, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(100, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(180, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(100, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(0, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 650);
        } else if (direction === 'right') {
                updatePlayer(0, 230, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(100, 230, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(180, 230, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(100, 230, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                updatePlayer(0, 230, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            }, 650);
        }
    };

               function movePlayer(e) {
            if (e.which === 37) {
                active = true;
                playerMove('left');
                player.destX -= 2;
            } else if (e.which === 39) {
                active = true;
                playerMove('right');
                player.destX += 2;
            }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            movePlayer(e);
    });
```

[Demo](http://boiling-ravine-7274.herokuapp.com/)
[Source Code](http://boiling-ravine-7274.herokuapp.com/javascripts/newGame.js)

Answer (score 0):

Store your timeouts in a variable, and use clearTimeout on every movement.
Even a better use in this case would be using a single interval, and clear the interval on the keyup event.

[edit]

Example with interval and a player action, only the animation time needs to be controlled.

```
var playerMovementInterval = null;

function movePlayerLeft () {
     var actions = [
         [0, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
         [100, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100],
         [180, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100],
         [100, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100],
         [0, 130, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
     ];

    var index = 0;
    clearInterval(playerMovementInterval);
    playerMovementInterval = setInterval(function() {
        updatePlayer.apply(window, actions[index]);
        index++;
        if (index > actions.length-1) clearInterval(playerMovementInterval);
    }, 200);                
}

var playerMove = function(direction) {

    if (direction === 'left') {
        movePlayerLeft();
    } else if (direction === 'right') {
.....
```

Comment: How could I use one interval for 3 different animations?

Comment: Make seperate player actions with the same interval for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could set active to false in the last timeout and only call move() if !active...